# Perl coding: How to extract part of a line in a text file and print it to an output file

Tags: perl

I have a large text files in the format shown below -

```
ID  SNP
FT  SNP 433
FT      /note="refAllele: T SNPstrains: 7083_1#5=C 7414_8#8=C 7480_8#49=C "
FT      /colour=1
FT  SNP 442
FT      /note="refAllele: T SNPstrains: 7065_8#2=C 7065_8#94=C 7083_1#2=C 7083_1#3=C 7083_1#41=C 7083_1#42=C 7083_1#43=C "
FT      /colour=1
FT  SNP 460
FT      /note="refAllele: T SNPstrains: 7564_8#14=C "
FT      /colour=1
FT  SNP 703
FT      /note="refAllele: G SNPstrains: 7521_5#39=A (non-synonymous) (AA Ala->Thr) "
FT      /colour=2
FT  SNP 937
FT      /note="refAllele: G SNPstrains: 7414_8#30=T (non-synonymous) (AA Val->Leu) "
FT      /colour=2
FT  SNP 1269
FT      /note="refAllele: G SNPstrains: 7480_7#22=A (synonymous) 7480_7#62=A (synonymous) "
FT      /colour=3
FT  SNP 1804
FT      /note="refAllele: T SNPstrains: 7414_7#66=A (non-synonymous) (AA Ser->Thr) 7414_8#44=A (non-synonymous) (AA Ser->Thr) 7521_6#54=A (non-synonymous) (AA Ser->Thr) "
FT      /colour=2
```

This is the code I used -

```
$file="input file";
open IN, "$file";
open OUT, ">output file";
print OUT "Coordinate   No of Strains   AA Change\n";
while(<IN>){
    if(m/^FT\s+SNP\s+(\d+)/){
            $SNP=$1;        
    }elsif(m/^FT\s+\/note="(.*)"/){
        $line=$1;
        $count = ($line =~ tr/=/=/);
        $line =~ m/\((AA \w+->\w+)\)\s*$/;
        $change = $1 || "";
    }elsif(m/^FT\s+\/colour=(\d+)/){
        print OUT "$SNP $count $change\n" if $cod{$1} eq "non";
    }
}
```

The aim is to have an output file that is like the one below (for the above part of text file)

```
Coordinates No of Strains AA Change
703         1             AA Ala->Thr
937         1             AA Val->Leu
1804        3             AA Ser->Thr
```

However, when I apply the code to the text file I receive an error: Use of uninitialised values ($count or $change) in concatenation (.) or string at line 23. The line in question is

```
print OUT "$SNP $count $change\n" if $cod{$1} eq "non";
```

The error refers to lines that contain

```
FT      /colour=2
```

i.e., lines that show a non-synonymous mutation, such as line 13 in the sample text.

Please be advised that I am a novice in programming and a large part of this code was not written by me. Any help would be appreciated!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not get that warning with the input given, assuming a few faked values in `%cod`. Neither do I get the output you claim.

Comment: What output do you get, if any?

Comment: I have repeated the use of this code for the whole file, which results in the output I said earlier, part of which is shown below -

    `Coordinate No of Strains AA Change  
    1299 1 AA Gin->His  
    3791 2 AA Val->Ala  
    4759 1 AA Gly->Ala  `

However if I do this for the sample text I gave for file 2, I get this output -

    `Coordinate No of Strains AA Change  
    1299 `

and the same use of uninitialised values error as when I use the code on the first file.

Comment: You should use a self-contained and correct example, where the input, code and output all match up. Then state your exact error messages. And it is a good idea to only ask questions about code which explicitly uses `strict` and `warnings`, and checks for easy mistakes such as `open` failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your program using more modern coding standards:

- I used `use strict;` and `use warnings;`
- I used spaces to help clarify the code
- I used more modern syntax for things like your loops and if/elsif statements

I found some minor glitches, but it didn't take me long to fix the issues. Here's your code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my $file = "input.txt";
my %cod = ( 1 => "red", 2 => "non", 3 => "green" );
open my $in, "<", "$file";
open my $out, ">", "output.txt";
say $out "Coordinate   No of Strains   AA Change";

my $SNP;
my $count;
my $change;
while ( my $line = <$in> ) {
    chomp $line;
    say qq(DEBUG: Line = "$line");
    if ( $line =~ /^FT\s+SNP\s+(\d+)/ ){
        $SNP = $1;        
        say qq(\$SNP = $1;);
    } 
    elsif ( $line =~ /^FT\s+\/note="(.*)"/) {
        my $note = $1;
        say qq(my \$note = $1);
        $count = ($note =~ tr/=/=/);
        $note =~ /\((AA \w+->\w+)\)\s*$/;
        $change = $1 || "";
    }
    elsif ( $line =~ /^FT\s+\/colour=(\d+)/ ) {
        say qq(Code = $1);
        if ( $cod{$1} eq "non" ) {
            printf $out "%-12.12s %-15.15s %s\n",  $SNP, $count, $change;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the output:

```
Coordinate   No of Strains   AA Change
703          1               AA Ala->Thr
937          1               AA Val->Leu
1804         3               AA Ser->Thr
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

That output is what I am looking for, although when I applied your code to the entire file I found this error:  

DEBUG: Line = "FT  SNP 703"
$SNP = 703
DEBUG: Line = "FT     /note="refAllele: G SNPstrains: 7521_5#39=A (non-synonymous) (AA Ala->Thr) "
DEBUG: Line = "FT      /colour=2"
Code = 2

Use of uninitialised value ($count or $change) in printf at Script.txt line 33 <$in> line xxxx.

I have used the above non-synonymous change as an example but it appears to have happened for all. The output is as you said, except only the coordinates of all NS changes are listed.

Comment: I have a few debug lines in it. They're just print or say statements. I use DEBUG statements to help debug my program. Just remove the `say` statements to get rid of the debug stuff. However, if you're getting an uninitialized value, you're not parsing your input as you think you are. Use the extraneous debug output to figure out why you're getting an uninitialized value. Maybe your count isn't working as you expect. Maybe there are a few lines that aren't conforming to your expected input. See why `$change` or `$count` aren't being set.

Comment: I have looked at the full file - I see no evidence of the format differing in any way from that of the sample text I gave above. Also I tried the code you gave me and had the same result with uninitialised errors - it didn't give me the output that you posted above.

Comment: Interestingly, I just applied your code to another file I have that is of the same format, and I didn't get the uninitialised values error and got the correct output as per your example above. Does this mean there must be a formatting discrepancy that I have not noticed?

Comment: If you have a bug in a program, you _debug_ it. Print out all lines as you read them in. Then, print out which part of your if statement is handling that line. Print out how the if statement is manipulating the data too. When you get the `uninitialized` error (which is why you use `use warnings;`, you can take a look at the last few lines of debugging output and see what could be causing the problem. After all, you have the line as read, and you see how the line is being parsed. Maybe `$count` isn't being set because `tr /=/=/` isn't finding any equal signs. Find out by looking at the output.